# how to make login other than users table in cake php 3.4

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create login authentication in cakephp other than user table . I have read many articles which says to replace  **userModel =>'mytablename'** but its not working at all .
I tried to work with cake php book article but it also returned an error
**Call to a member function config()....**

Thanks in Advance

AppController.php

```
    public function initialize()
    {

        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Members',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Unauthorized Access',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'contact',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'userModel'=>'Members'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
   $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
            AuthComponent::ALL => [
              'userModel' => 'Members',
         ],
         'Form',
         'Basic'
        ]);
}
```

login.ctp

```
<?= $this->Form->Create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('contact') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end()?>
```

MembersController.php

```
public function login(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $user= $this->Auth->identify();
            var_dump($user);
            exit();
        }
}
```

My Table Structure  with Values

```
CREATE TABLE `Members` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mailid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Members` (`name`, `contact`, `mailid`, `password`) VALUES
('abc ', '9999999999', 'abc@gmail.com', '12345'),
('def', '8888888888', 'def@gmail.com', '12345');
```

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with [**the asking guide**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information to your question that helps readers to be able to reproduce your problem. Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the corresponding context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error - thanks!

Comment: I have edited my post with code and error ,Please suggest any approriate solution

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update, I duplicated your issue. Here is list of changes, that I made:

In AppController:

```
public function initialize(){
    /*---*/
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Members',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Members',
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'contact',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    /*---*/
}
```

As you can see from code above, you do not need to use AuthComponent::config(), if you are passing parameters in Controller::loadComponent().

In members table (in MySQL): added id - primary index with autoincrement.

But strangely, after these changes AuthComponent::identify() still was unable to identify user. In past, I made couple applications with non-standard user database, and it all worked perfectly. So I digged deeper.

In SQL log there was even a query from AuthComponent, and it was able to find user. But it failed to check if password was correct. As password is checked in PHP, not MySQL, there must be something in cake which is causing that. After some digging, I realized that it can be an issue with password hashing - all of my previous apps had passwords hashed from very beginning, and here password are in evil plaintext. So I added hashing in Entity:

Member.php:

```
/*---*/

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

/*---*/

protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    if (strlen($password) > 0) {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

Detailed instruction how to add password hashing can be found here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

I edited one user to hash his password, and... it worked. I can not clearly tell why it does not work without hashing, but as you SHOULD use hashing in first place, I won't call it a bug.

Comment: Hey I tried this but in my controller $this->Auth->identify() method always returning false

Comment: It's probably because it can not identify user based on request data. By default, AuthComponent::identify() will search your request data for fields "username" and "password". If you wish to use another fields for authentication, you can alter this behaviour by passing following options to AuthComponent:config(): `'authenticate' => ['form' => ['username' => 'your_username_field', 'password' => 'your_password_field']]` AuthComponent is well described in CakePHP cookbook, so I encourage you to check it: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer i have one more issue I want user login using either contact or mailid.....I have searched it and found Multicolumn but it hasnt worked for me...

Comment: I don't know cake way to do this, but one thing you could do is to manually find user by email or username, and adjust $this->request->data accordingly, before running AuthComponent::identify().

Comment: I also tried Customizing Find Query and using finder=>auth but in findAuth method $options returning null array ...